# Change appBar icon real-time with StreamBuilder - flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to change appbar icon real-time (action) with `StreamBuilder` result,

So, I use this method,

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isOk = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: isOk ? Icon(Icons.edit) : Icon(Icons.edit_off))
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, streamSnapshot) {
           // set this -------------------------------------------------------
           if (streamSnapshot.data!['newRequests'].length != 0) {
             setState(() {
               isOk = true;
             });
           }
           //---------------------------------------------------------------------
          return Center(
              child: CustomText(
            size: 60,
            text: streamSnapshot.data!['newRequests'].length != 0 ? "Have" : "0",
            textColor: darkblueColor,
          ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It doesn't work. It shows error like this:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below

```
 AppBar(
    actions: [
      StreamBuilder(
        stream: stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return  IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: snapshot.data!['newRequests'].length != 0 ? Icon(Icons.edit) : Icon(Icons.edit_off))]),
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: I use many StreamBuilder on this screen. is it not a problem?

Comment: Not getting your questions

Comment: Means, what is your mean by stream builder

Comment: I use StreamBuilder many times on the home screen, I asked that Is it affect app preference. (This code example is not my real home page.)

Comment: If you have many strembuilder then direct wrap on appbar it self

Comment: StreamBuilder(c,s){
return appBar()
}

Comment: like above .........

Comment: @rahulVFlutterAndroid is someone does respect your time, leave them

Answer (score 0):

Created `StreamBuilder` inside appBar like this, It solved my problem. @rahulVFlutterAndroid's answer helped me to do this.

```
   AppBar(
        actions: [
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return  IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: snapshot.data!['newRequests'].length != 0 ? Icon(Icons.edit) : Icon(Icons.edit_off))]),
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: @Yeasin What do you think about this?

Comment: it might be  calling stream two times if I am not wrong, I might  choose valueNotfier over this.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, I will read about valueNotifier